# Why does freeing a dynamically created 2D long long int array gives SIGTRAP in c?

Tags: c, pointers, exception, runtime-error

I am creating a simple 2D `long long in`t array dynamically in `C`, but `free`ing the array gives `SIGTRAP` ? I am really confused.The same code for `int` works perfectly fine. Why using it with `long long int` gives `SIGTRAP` ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i,j;
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
long long int** ptr=(long long int**)calloc(n,sizeof(long long int*));
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
ptr[i]=(long long int*)calloc(n,sizeof(long long int));

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
for(j=i;j<=n;j++)
ptr[i-1][j-1]=i+j;

free(ptr[i]);
free(ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: Why are you looping over 50 elements?

Comment: Change `for(i=0;i<50;i++)` to `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` in both loops

Comment: Sorry it was a typing mistake i edited it.

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava Hello. After the latest edit, does the problem persist?

Comment: can stack overflow not just parse c code snippets for parentheses preceding a malloc and automatically add the appropriate ubiquitous comment?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes the problem still persist please have a look at the final edit

Comment: Out of bounds access. See my answer.

Comment: There ought to be `n + 1` calls to `free()`: **Exactly which** call to `free()` causes the crash?

Comment: Also you are expected to properly indent your code, at least in the case you are expecting us to read it.

Comment: @alk sir, IMHO, in this particular case, the very first call. as `i` is `n+1` then. (`i` value held after `for` loop):-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes sure, for the code currently shown (as per edit 2). I however assume this isn't the "real" code.

Comment: @juanchopanza sir, isn't the `for` loop condition here is `i<=n`? so the failure case in `for` loop has to be `i>n`, right? and here we've use `i++`, so...

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, you're absolutely right. I must be sleep-typing.

Comment: @juanchopanza I would like to blame OP for using non-conventional indexing scheme.

Answer (score 1):

in `ptr`, you're allocating memory for `n` times `sizeof (long long int *)`, but you're looping for a hardcoded value usning `for(i=0;i<50;i++)`.

In case, `n` is less that `50`, you're accessing out-of-bound memory by saying `ptr[i]`. Results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, you should always check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure proper input, otherwise, as the code is currently written, in case `scanf()` fails, you'll face UB due to use of uninitialized local variable `n`.

Note: You [need not and do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

---

EDIT:

This time, the issues are

1. accessing out-of-bound memory, in `free(ptr[i]);` without a *reset* of `i` value.
2. Resulting Memory leak due to improper usage of index.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid after the last edit of the question :(

Comment: @AlterMann Right you are. but after the latest edit, should there be any issue(s)?

Comment: Now his code is fine,  there must be something wrong with the input,  OP, check the result of `scanf`

Comment: Though I agree with " not cast the retval of malloc and friends" I still wonder, why most of the online tutorials, which I was reading, mostly did this. And for sure, the authors are no dummies,

Comment: @icbytes, it's a guess ... They are trying to write code compilable in both languages,  C and C++

Comment: sorry to bother everyone now the code is finally edited which gives SIGTRAP for unknown reasons , please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with correct indentation for the structure.

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long long int** ptr=(long long int**)calloc(n,sizeof(long long int*));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        ptr[i]=(long long int*)calloc(n,sizeof(long long int));

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=i;j<=n;j++)
            ptr[i-1][j-1]=i+j;

    free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the line `free(ptr[i]);` is only executed after the loop through all the `i`s has exited.  The loop exits when `i == n + 1`. `ptr` has been allocated with `n` blocks of memory indexed from 0 to n - 1.  You are trying to free a garbage pointer that is after the end of the array.

I suspect what you really want is:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
{
    free(ptr[i]);
}
```

It's a matter of style, but I prefer to always put the braces in on loop and conditional bodies even if there is only one statement in the loop.